# jWebScokets explorer support

Tags: html, websocket

I'm using jWebSockets to run a small internet app. Even though the website says there is explorer support using a flash bridge and this should be transparent, I can't seem to have my app running on explorer.
Is there something that needs to be done to have support for explorer that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Flash WebSocket implementation like [this](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) to work, you need to run a Flash Policy File server on port 843 serving a policy file which instructs Flash player to allow outbound socket connections. Obviously, you also need to include the relevant Flash files in your client HTML page. Just follow the instructions in the reference. This specific bridge works with IE8/9 and also other WebSocket lacking browsers with Flash support like the native Android browser (pre Chrome Mobile).

Comment: The link 'this' in your answer seems to lead to the same flash-bridge used by jWebSocket. They say in their page that I'm required to run it on Tomcat on port 80 for it to work, and nothing else. I'm currently _not_ running their server using tomcat. Am I correct to assume that tomcat can function as the Flash Policy File server? or do you mean I need something separate in addition?

Comment: As said, you need a Flash policy file server running on port 843 in addition to your WebSocket server running on whatever port.